# How to implement settings in an iOS app using MVC

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, model-view-controller, architecture

I'm using the MVC architectural pattern, and I'd like to make a settings screen for my app for the user to be able to be able to customize certain parts of the application.

What would the model object be here? I have thought about making a `Setting` (model) object, but all the settings are different. What is a clean way to do this?

(Examples of existing apps are most welcome)

Answer (score 0):

iOS applications use class NSUserDefaults to persistently store settings as key-value pairs. This is the 'model' part of it.

Example (Swift):

```
UserDefaults.standard.set("userValue", forKey: "userSetting")

let userValue = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey:"userSetting") as? String
```

The view/controller to edit settings can be set up as a viewController in the storyboard, or by using the 'Settings' app with a Settings.Bundle.

Comment: Thanks. I know about NSUserDefaults. My question is about class structure using the MVC pattern. (i.e. where code would go)